# ScrollView content size not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I setup up a ScrollView as root view for one of my view controllers. When I dragged the scroll view from the Interface builder, the scroll came up with an initial size of 220x120.

In that view controller viewDidLoad method, I have this code.

```
UIImage *iphone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone4s.jpg"];
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:iphone];
[self.view addSubview:imageview];


[(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentSize:[iphone size]];
```

the `iphone` image size is 600x800.

But the scroll view still is in size 220x120 when the view loads up on the screen. Should I do anything else to stretch the scrollView. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `contentSize` is not the same as the size of the UIScrollView. Normally you'll have a bigger content size in order to be able to scroll:

```
+-------------------+
|x------------+     |
||            |     | 
||            |     |
|+------------+     |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

The inner rect in this sketch is the scroll view size (your 220x120), what you see in the screen, while the outer rect is the  actual size of the object (600x800 in your case).  Manipulating `contentOffset` point (the x in the figure) you can change which portion of the object is visible.

If you don't need the image to be scrollable, you don't need a UIScrollView at all. Try with the UIImageView, change its `frame` and check the different values of its `contentMode` property.

Also, don't forget that views can auto adjust its size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
`

```
UIImage *iphone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone4s.jpg"];
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:iphone];
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);

[(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentSize:[iphone size]];
```

`
If this will work for you - just stretch it in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`[(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentSize:[imageview size]];`

Comment: there is no size property for image view